# Submitting multiple inputs with same name

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-data

Ok, so I have form for creating polls. I want to use AJAX request and able user to attach image instead of question, so I use FormData for this.

I could't find any solution for working with multiple input with same name (named like this: "name[]"). I tried this option:

```
var fdata = new FormData();
fdata.append('answers[]', $('input[name="answer[]"]').val());
```

But it doesn't work. I know I could use `.each()`, but I don't want different name for each question, so I don't have to rebuild PHP side too much.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to append each value in turn. Currently you are only appending the first one (because that is what `val()` returns.

```
$('input[name="answer[]"]').each(function (index, member) {
    var value = $(member).val();
    fdata.append('answers[]', value);
});
```

Comment: Yep. I didn't notice that previous solution gives comma seperated string. This is correct. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `$('input[name="answer[]"]').val()` isn't giving you what you need; it returns the first input element's value. Instead, you want an array of values:

```
var values = [];
$('input[name="answer[]"]').each(function(i, item) {
    values.push(item.value);
});

fdata.append('answers[]', values);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j5ezgxe9/

Comment: The part "'input[name="answer[]"]'" won't work, you will need an iterator so the output of the html would be 'input[name="answer["+i+"]"]'

Comment: Nope. That stringifies the array to a single, comma separated string. It would be possible to split it apart on the server … unless any of the inputs contained a comma as data.